# Algorithm for finding the layout of an object of some class in memory in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A();
    virtual void foo();
};
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual ~B();
    virtual void foo();
};
```

Layout of an object of class B in memory looks as following:

[image]

It becomes hard to layout the object of some class in memory when we talk about multiple inheritance, especially when we talk about the diamond inheritance, or when we talk about a virtual class like:

```
class E : public C, public virtual D, public virtual B {
public :
    E() {
        cout << "E::E()" << endl;
    }
    E(int x) : D(x) {
        cout << "E::E(int)" << endl;
    }
};
```

I was looking for some pseudo-algorithm which explains how to display this layout. Is there such algorithm I can follow and build manually those layouts (without the virtual tables)?

**EDIT**: I got the following example:

[image]

And the memory layout in the solution section is:

[image]

I just don't understand why it is shown like this. So I thought there is some kind of algorithm I can follow in order to build it.

Comment: There's no fixed or "standard" layout. It depends on the ABI and the compiler.

Comment: note that already the virtual table is a implementation detail. It is a prominent one, because (almost?) every implementation is using it, though the c++ standard does not care about virtual tables and it is nothing you can portably rely on

Comment: That diagram looks misleading to me. The gaps imply that the `E` object isn't contiguous

Comment: Note that there's nothing portable you can do with the knowledge of such a monstrosity's layout. It sounds like you are being taught C++, by a teacher who has some grave misconceptions

Answer (score 2):

That layout depends on the ABI which your compiler is targetting. You should study that ABI's documentation to learn how classes are expected to be layed out in memory.

For example, [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) uses the [Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/).

Comment: @vesii Doesn't change anything regarding the answer. Each ABI will have its own rules (= algorithm) for C++ class layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the diagram you've been given thinks that C++ is C with extras, and has made assumptions about implementation-defined behaviour from that standpoint.

It's reading the *base-specifier-list* left to right, depth first, and assuming that virtual inheritance is a single pointer. Each labelled box corresponds to the non-static data member subobjects of the classes (of which there are none). The unlabelled boxes are pointers to virtual bases.

We start at `E`. It has a non-virtual `C` base, a virtual `B` base and a virtual `D` base.
The `C` has a virtual `B` subobject, which becomes a pointer.
The virtual `B` already has a pointer, which will point to the same place as the `C`'s base.
The virtual `D` needs a pointer.

This ends the non-virtual bases of `E`, but there are still virtual bases that don't yet have storage.

We make a `B`, which has a non-virtual `A`, and record the offset in `E`.
We make a `D`, which has a non-virtual `B`, which has a non-virtual `A`, and record the offset in `E`

Answer (score 0):

Except for standard layout types, it is implementation defined and perhaps also unspecified:

For the multiple inheritance patterns you can use static_cast to glean how it is layout - albeit there is no gaurentee even then: this looks like this:

```
void* offsetToB = static_cast<B*>(static_cast<A*>(nullptr));
```

**DISCLAIMER:** this is unsafe to rely on.